# Unable to add a variable assigned as a random number

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

I've successfully created a random number generator, and have used the random module before. But I am trying to add a touch of random to my weather simulator project. My issue is that when I add a variable assigned as a random number between 1 and 99, it just wont let me do it.

Here's the code. Can someone help me figure out the right way to do this?

```
import random
from random import*
t = 100
wmph = 51
h = 25
randwmph = random.randint(1, 99)

print ("\nDynamic Weather Simulator | V.004\n")

while True:

if t >= 0 and t <= 150:

    print("\nHumidity:",h)
    print("\nTemperature:",t)
    print("\nWindSpeed:",wmph)
    print("\n________________\n")

if t >= 5 and t <= 100:
    h = h + 0.6

if h >= 50 and t >= 33:
    print("\nRAINFALL\n")

if h >= 50 and t <= 32:
    print("\nSNOWFALL\n")

if h >= 55:
    h = h - 20
if wmph >= 30:
    t = t - 2
if wmph <= 29:
    t = t + 1

if wmph >= 60:
    wmph = wmph - randwmph # UNABLE TO USE THIS VARIABLE AS A NUMBER, EVEN THOUGH IT IS ASSIGNED AS A RANDOM NUMBER BETWEEN 1 and 99

else:
    wmph = wmph + 4
```

Comment: What do you mean by "won't let me do it" and "unable to use this variable as a number"? Are you getting an error message? See [mcve].

Comment: Please give a proper error description and check your code's indentation and spacing!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  For future reference please see [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to increase your chance of getting a meaningful answer.  Namely in this case - what is the expected outcome and what is the error encountered.  For Python, keep in mind that indentation is important (e.g. are all the codes below the `while` block supposed to be part of the loop? If so, they should be indented.  If not: the `while` statement shouldn't be there.

Comment: Remove the line `from random import *` or use only `randint`.

Comment: When you `from random import *` you overwrite the module `random` (imported in the previous line) with the function `random.random` from the `random` module. The `random` function doesn't have an attribute `randint`.

Comment: @kindall You should post that as an answer. I've been looking for a dupe target, but can't find one.

Answer (score 1):

```
import random
from random import*
```

when you use this style for importing,there is no need for random.randint(). You should just use randint(1,99).

Otherwise replace that with just `import random`
and the rest should be fine.

Comment: Not necessarily.  The `while True:` is going to throw an error unless the code is properly indented.  Other than that, yes, removing `from random import*` should fix it.

Comment: The code might be indented in OP's editor, one should give him a benefit of doubt that he doesn't know how to indent it on SO

Comment: Actually, using `from random import *` is _not_ a good idea. Such wildcard imports aka "star" imports dump all the imported names into your namespace, which is messy and can lead to name collisions. They also make it harder to read the code because you need to know & remember where all the different names come from. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386714/why-is-import-bad

Comment: I didn't read the rest actually. I just looked at the problem with the random variable since that's what he wanted to know.

Comment: @iamauser: I'm inclined to err on the side of caution.  Too many times I've seen errors caused by careless mistakes like these.  Especially for a beginner, these things should be pointed out even if it's probably fine on their side.  Just so they don't come back with a second error.

Answer (score 1):

As kindall mentions in the comments, the cause of your error is

```
from random import*
```

which imports all the names defined in the `random` module and dumps them into your global namespace. One of those names is `random`, which is the `random` function, and that new name clobbers the previous assignment of that name to the module itself, which was performed by

```
import random
```

So now the name `random` refers to the `random` function and not the `random` module. And so when you try to do

```
random.randint(1, 99)
```

you'll get this error message:

```
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'randint'
```

because the `random` function doesn't have a `randint` attribute.

---

In general, you should avoid such wildcard imports (aka "star" imports). They dump all the imported names into your namespace, which is messy, and as you have discovered, they can lead to name collisions. They also make it harder to read the code because you need to know and remember where all the different names come from. Please see [Why is “import *” bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2386714/4014959) for further information on this important topic.

Comment: Yes, Ive fixed that. Thank you though! It seems like after the fix the code runs, but is not random. Ive edited my original question above..please read and help :)

Comment: @taylorbeeler Please don't change your question after it's received relevant answers. Your question and its answers aren't only to help you, they should also be helpful to future readers. But editing it like that makes the existing answers irrelevant. If you have a new question, you can ask a fresh question.

Comment: @taylorbeeler  However your new problem is because you aren't calling the `random.randint` function inside your `while` loop, so it just keeps using the same original random number that was generated outside the loop.

Comment: It says to edit my question if I need to add more details, and so I did. But I understand. And thanks for answering, very much. Is there any way you could help me figure out how to add it to my loop? I was under the impression that it was...

Comment: @taylorbeeler Just move the line `randwmph = random.randint(1, 99)` inside the `while` loop. You could put it directly under the `while` line (properly indented), but I suggest putting it just under the `if wmph >= 60:` line, (indented so it's inside the `if` block`) so it only gets generated if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Replace "random.randint(1,99)" with just "randint(1,99)"
```

And you HAVE TO indent your while loop. Plus I have added a time delay for better visualization..

```
import random
from random import*
import time
t = 100
wmph = 51
h = 25
randwmph = randint(1,99)

print ("\nDynamic Weather Simulator | V.004\n")

while True:

    if t >= 0 and t <= 150:

        print("\nHumidity:",h)
        print("\nTemperature:",t)
        print("\nWindSpeed:",wmph)
        print("\n________________\n")

    if t >= 5 and t <= 100:
        h = h + 0.6

    if h >= 50 and t >= 33:
        print("\nRAINFALL\n")

    if h >= 50 and t <= 32:
        print("\nSNOWFALL\n")

    if h >= 55:
        h = h - 20
    if wmph >= 30:
        t = t - 2
    if wmph <= 29:
        t = t + 1

    if wmph >= 60:
        wmph = wmph - randwmph # UNABLE TO USE THIS VARIABLE AS A NUMBER, EVEN THOUGH IT IS ASSIGNED AS A RANDOM NUMBER BETWEEN 1 and 99

    else:
        wmph = wmph + 4
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Thanks everyone! I got it to work. It was removing the "from random import*" - I dont even know how I got into the habit of doing that..

And thanks for the time.sleep line!! I had no idea! Definitely helps.

Comment: WAIT, it doesnt work. Still. It seems to subtract a specific amount each time, rather than a random number. It's always the same

Comment: Add "randwmph = randint(1,99)" line inside while loop.